# How do you rename a variable in R?

Tags: r

If I have a variable

`x <- "foo"`

and another variable

`y <- 1:5`

is there a way I can rename `y` to `foo` while keeping it equal to `1:5`?

Comment: May be `assign`  `assign(x, y);  foo#
[1] 123`

Comment: sorry, what you suggested worked for what I asked specifically, but in my much more complicated code it keeps giving me an error.  I assumed because what I was trying to preserve is a long vector, not a number, thats why I edited it.  However, what you suggested does work for my edits, not sure what the issue is and my code is way to long to post so thats why I simplified it.  I keep getting the error that I have an invalid first argument within assign.

Comment: @akrun That should be an answer, no? To me, it's clear what's being asked here, though it may be a dupe. (And the answer I currently see below makes no sense to me.)

Comment: @Frank It looks like a dupe.  but I can't vote to close as I already voted for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `comment()` so that `foo` was an attribute of `y`. For example, try:

```
x <- "foo"
y <- 1:5

comment(y) <- x

str(y)
attr(y, "comment")
```